# Как лучше написать функцию сортировки и фильтрации массива с несколькими параметрами?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть каталог игр, в котором список игр проходит через несколько фильтров.

[image: фильтрация списка игр]

Игры разделены по платформам (HTC, PSVR, PS5, Избранное), при переходе по табу срабатывает вычисляемое свойство, для PS5 это showPS5Games, которое принимает выбранный жанр (genre), сортировку (selectedSort), чекбокс "Для детей" (isChild), чекбокс "На двоих" (isLocalMultiplayer) и поиск игры по названию/тегу/жанру (query). Все параметры могут быть комбинированы любым образом. Я написал разветвлённую функцию со множествои if на каждую возможную комбинацию, что не оптимизировано и не эстетично. Также почему-то не срабатывает фильтрация массива по обоим выбранным чекбоксам, корректно срабатывает только по одному. Как лучше её переписать? Полный код showPS5Games:

```
showPS5Games: state => (
  query,
  genre,
  isChild,
  isLocalMultiplayer,
  selectedSort
) => {
  if (genre == "все" && isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category == "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category == "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category == "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (genre === "все" && isChild) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (isChild) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (genre === "все" && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (genre === "все") {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" && game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" && game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  }
  var filteredGames = [];
  if (selectedSort == "ascending") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
  } else if (selectedSort == "descending") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
  } else if (selectedSort == "bygenre") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.genre.localeCompare(b.genre));
  } else if (selectedSort == "bytag") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.tag.localeCompare(b.tag));
  } else {
    filteredGames = tmpArray;
  }
  return filteredGames;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
showPS5Games: state => (
  query,
  genre,
  isChild,
  isLocalMultiplayer,
  selectedSort
) => {
  var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
    return game.category == "ps5" &&
      (genre == "все" || game.genre === genre) &&
      (!isChild || game.isChild) &&
      (!isLocalMultiplayer || game.isLocalMultiplayer) &&
      (query.length == 0 || game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query) || game.genre.includes(query) || game.tag.includes(query));
  });
  }
  var filteredGames = [];
  if (selectedSort == "ascending") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
  } else if (selectedSort == "descending") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
  } else if (selectedSort == "bygenre") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.genre.localeCompare(b.genre));
  } else if (selectedSort == "bytag") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.tag.localeCompare(b.tag));
  } else {
    filteredGames = tmpArray;
  }
  return filteredGames;
}
```